# (Linked List) My code compiles, but it's not printing out anything

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I posted this question earlier and a comment suggested I make a Link class and other suggestions (though I could not do all of them). I attempted to do so and now my code at least compiles, but it doesn't print out anything. I would appreciate the help.

So my project is to get a file called "contacts.txt", read in the data and put the data into a node. Then, I put that node into a list. I purge duplicates and print out the resulting list. I'm trying to get the reading in the data and the printing part down first but I'm having problem printing out my list.

A line of contact looks like:

```
Angelina M. Pierre 212 555 1234
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
typedef int ElementType;


class Node
{
private:
  ElementType first, mid, last, phone;
  Node *next;

  friend class List;
public:
/*  Node(Element){
    first = "";
    mid = "";
    last = "";
    phone = "";
  }; */
  Node(ElementType f, ElementType mi, ElementType sur, ElementType ph){
        first = f;
        mid = mi;
        last = sur;
        phone = ph;
        next = NULL;
  };

  Node* getNext()
  {
    return next;
  }

  void setFirst(ElementType firstName){
    first = firstName;
  }
  ElementType getFirst()
  {
    return first;
  }

  void setMid(ElementType middleI){
    mid = middleI;
  }
  ElementType getMid()
  {
    return mid;
  }

  void setLast(ElementType lastName){
    last = lastName;
  }
  ElementType getLast()
  {
    return last;
  }

  void setPhone(ElementType phoneNum){
    phone = phoneNum;
  }
  ElementType getPhone()
  {
    return phone;
  }

void printNode(){
  cout << first << " " << mid << "" << last << "" << phone;
}


};
typedef Node* NodePointer;

/*------------------------------------------------------*/

class List {
private:
  Node* first;

public:
List(){
  first = NULL;
}

NodePointer getFirst(){
  return first;
};

/*--------------------------------------------------------*/

void insert(ElementType fir, ElementType midd, ElementType las, ElementType phon, NodePointer pos){
  NodePointer pN;
  if(pos == first){
    pN = new Node(fir, midd, las, phon);
    pN->next = pos;
    first = pN;
  }

  else{
    pN = new Node(fir, midd, las, phon);
    pN->next = pos->next;
  }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/

void remove(NodePointer pos){
  NodePointer pN;
  if(pos == NULL){
    return;
  }
  else {
    if(pos == first){
      first = first->next;
      delete pos;
    }
    else{
      pN = first;
      while(pN->next != pos){
        pN = pN->next;
        pN->next = pos->next;
        delete pos;
      }
    }
  }
}


//Accessor
//bool empty();
void printContactList(){
    NodePointer pN;
    for(pN = first; pN != NULL; pN = pN->next){
      pN->printNode();
      cout << endl;
    }
  }
  friend void copyList (List &L, List &M);
};



void readData(){
  List L;
//I had to do multiple ph (phone numbers) because when I would read it in, it would only take the first three numbers and not the entire phone number. 
  ElementType fi, mi, la, ph, ph1, ph2;
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\contacts.txt");

  fin >> fi >> mi >>la >> ph >> ph1 >> ph2;

  while(!fin.eof()){
  L.insert(fi, mi, la, ph, L.getFirst());
  fin >> fi >> mi >>la >> ph >> ph1 >> ph2;
  //fin >> fi;

}
  L.printContactList();

}
int main()
{

    readData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, my tidbit about `!inFile.eof()` being considered wrong is still important here. I believe you are getting stuck in an infinite loop because of it. Please, read that link if you haven't. Instead, you need something more like `while(inFile >> item1 >> item2 >> ... >> itemN){/*code*/}`, so that the condition is instead, semantically,  "Can I read more information from my file?".

Comment: @Shaavin When I first submitted my project, my professor told me I shouldn't put while(infile >> item1 >>item2 ) (I did that before changing it to .eof) and said if I submitted my code with it that way, he would mark it wrong. That's why I'm trying to use .eof. I'm not really sure why he wants it that way.

Comment: Oh, got'cha. I disagree with his stance, but I totally understand needing to stick with the instructor's orders. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's the problem

```
typedef int ElementType;
```

`ElementType` is an integer.

Here's the data

```
Angelina M. Pierre 212 555 1234
```

The data is three strings followed by three integers.

And here's the variables you are trying to read the data into

```
ElementType fi, mi, la, ph, ph1, ph2;
```

All the variables are integers but some of your data is strings. So your reads are failing!

Even the briefest period of debugging should have told you this. Just putting a `cout << ...` statement inside your reading loop would have told you what was wrong. I know programming is difficult but you only learn by practising. Try and be a bit more self-reliant.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've been working on this project for some time by myself and it's overdue by a few days because I've been so stuck and didn't know what to do. It's just been so frustrating. I really appreciate this.